# How do i pivot a table?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a dynamic single row  Table like:

```
PersonId|FirstName|LastName|Address|PhoneNumber
-----------------------------------------------
1        Anuj      Tamrakar  NY     +525418
```

I want to pivot this table and want an output in temp table like:

```
PersonalDetails|Value
----------------------
PersonId        1
FirstName       Anuj
LastName        Tamrakar
Address         NY
PhoneNumber     +525418
```

The first Table is a dynamic single row temp table. For this example, I have 5 columns. I may have more or less columns depending on my criteria

Comment: You simply display the column name and the column value, but you need to do this in some other program. Or do you need this in sql in another table?

Comment: I need it in sql and in another table

Comment: Keep in mind that your unpivot operation won't make very much sense for the case of multiple records/IDs, because it won't be possible to determine which records belong to which ID.

Answer (score 4):

You actually want to [**`UNPIVOT`**](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx):

```
SELECT  PersonalDetails, Value
FROM 
   (SELECT CAST([PersonId] AS VARCHAR(MAX)) AS [PersonId], 
           CAST([FirstName] AS VARCHAR(MAX))  AS [FirstName],
           CAST([LastName] AS VARCHAR(MAX)) AS [LastName],
           CAST([Address] AS VARCHAR(MAX)) AS [Address],
           CAST([PhoneNumber] AS VARCHAR(MAX)) AS [PhoneNumber]
   FROM mytable) p
UNPIVOT
   (Value FOR PersonalDetails IN 
      ([PersonId], [FirstName], [LastName], [Address], [PhoneNumber])
) AS unpvt;
```

All 'to-be-unpivoted' fields have to be of *the same type*, hence the use of `CAST`.

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/7fb129/8)

For a dynamic number of columns you have to use dynamic sql:

```
DECLARE @cols VARCHAR(MAX) = ''
DECLARE @cast_cols VARCHAR(MAX) = ''
DECLARE @qry VARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @cols = @cols + ',[' + COLUMN_NAME + ']'
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'mytable' AND TABLE_SCHEMA='dbo'

SELECT @cast_cols = @cast_cols + ',CAST([' + COLUMN_NAME + '] AS VARCHAR(MAX)) AS [' + COLUMN_NAME + ']'
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'mytable' AND TABLE_SCHEMA='dbo'

SET @cols = STUFF(@cols, 1, 1, '')
SET @cast_cols = STUFF(@cast_cols, 1, 1, '')    

SET @qry = 'SELECT  PersonalDetails, Value FROM (' 
           + @cast_cols +        
          'FROM mytable) p
           UNPIVOT
           (Value FOR PersonalDetails IN (' + @cols + ')
           ) AS unpvt'
EXEC (@qry)
```

Comment: thanks for your help. But the thing is, its  a dynamic single row temp table. In some case,  i could just have 5 columns and in some just more or less. Whatever be  the case i just need an output as above. any other ideas will be appreciated :)

Comment: @AnujTamrakar In that you have to use dynamic sql and build the field list of the pivot operation dynamically.

Answer (score 2):

If you really have a single row in the original table, then you can use a series of `UNION` operations to get your output:

```
SELECT 'PersonId'    AS PersonalDetails, PersonId AS    Value
FROM yourTable
UNION ALL
SELECT 'FirstName'   AS PersonalDetails, FirstName AS   Value
FROM yourTable
UNION ALL
SELECT 'LastName'    AS PersonalDetails, LastName AS    Value
FROM yourTable
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Address'     AS PersonalDetails, Address AS     Value
FROM yourTable
UNION ALL
SELECT 'PhoneNumber' AS PersonalDetails, PhoneNumber AS Value
FROM yourTable
```

Comment: actually its a dynamic single row temp table. For Instance, I could have 5 columns and in other case just 2. Whatever be the number of columns I need output as above. so probably a dynamic SQL code would be really appreciated. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM sys.columns WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID('dbo.yourTableName')
```

This gives you your column names. You simply insert the column names in your new table and use ``, `insert into temp(PersonalDetails, Value) values(column1,`select column1 from SingleRowTable

Comment: actually i needed this too but in some other case. TY

Comment: Well, this simply takes every single column from your table, no matter how many columns you have. After that, you can build your second column with the value from your table.